# Return multiple rows with same value in first column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a document that I would like to have a sheet that searches another sheet for a specific value that I type in (a name) and return content from all of the rows that have that value in their first column. Similar to vlookup, but include not just the content from the first row found.

In my document, the desired formulas will be on "lookup" and "example" is an example of how I would like it to function.

Comment: The spreadsheet you linked to is not publicly viewable. Please change the sharing settings to be viewable to anyone with the link.

Answer (score 5):

`filter` works, but with `query` you can get all needed columns with one command:

```
=query(Notes!A2:E, "select B, D, E where A = '"&B1&"'")
```

The messy end of query string is arranged so that if B1 contains Student Name, the  query becomes `"select B, D, E where A = 'Student Name'"`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a =filter(). You can filter down to a row in a range that corresponds to the row from a condition.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your sheet does work exactly how I wanted, appreciate it!