# Is there a formula I can use in Google Sheets to filter data on a daily basis?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to Google Sheets but was asked to create a digital lunch form for my school.  I created the form but I need the data collected to be separated on a daily basis.  Is there a formula I can use or will I have to create a page break daily to separate the data?

Comment: Sorry, just read the welcome that this site is for power users.  I'm not a power user yet.

Comment: You're in the right place, but the question is a bit unclear. There are no page breaks in Google Sheets. What is your actual goal: to have the data for today (or tomorrow) on a separate sheet for easy printing?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Filter` command in the Data menu.

With filters enabled, you can pick the desired value (or a range of values) for your "Date" column, including setting a condition that "Date is today" or "Date is tomorrow".

Does that do what you want?

Also see [Return multiple rows with same value in first column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84337/return-multiple-rows-with-same-value-in-first-column) which explains how to make a sheet that queries for desired rows from another sheet. The query could filter for the desired date.