# Google Sheets: Two Functions at Once? Countif and Sum Maybe?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to see how many times a person inputs the same answer into a form, and then take the top three people to use that certain answer. For example, people enter the "B Option", and I want to see the top three people to select "B Option" and how many times they did so.

This means I need to see A: all the instances of "B Option" getting picked (which is stored in column D), B: figure out which people did it the most (names stored in column A), and C: display both the names of the top users and the number of times they picked "B Option" somewhere.

I'll be honest, I have no idea how to even approach this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome. May I suggest that you need to break the task into pieces and then research those elements. For example, this Q&A from StackOverflow  [How to output the most common value and the number of occurrences of that value in spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070334/1330560) will give you the most common answer as well as the number of times that it was selected. To find the names of the people who selected that option, look at this Q&A from Webapps: [Return multiple rows with same value in first column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84346/196152).

Answer (score 0):

This answer creates a single formula to output the analysis that you want.

`=query(A1:D18,"select A, COUNT(D) where D='B' group by A order by Count(D) desc limit 3 label A 'Name' ")`

- The data is analysed using a `query`
- `where D='B'`selects only the "B" answers
- `select A, COUNT(D)` - returns the name and the frequency of "B" answers
- `order by Count(D) desc` - returns the data sorted by the frequency column, descending (highest values first)

---

**Sample**

[image: Sample]

Comment: This is amazingly helpful, thank you! Just trying to get it to fit my situation a little better. So far I have the following; let me know where I'm going wrong

`=query(C2:G656,"select C, COUNT(G) where G=$L2 group by C order by Count(G) desc limit 3")`

Comment: “where I'm going wrong” Sorry for the rudeness of my previous reply. Of course, I can help. There could be several reasons that your formula won't work but I do need to see your data, etc. Would you please share a spreadsheet containing some data? Thanks.